# Msql Crosstab month rows as columns?

Tags: mysql

Good morning, I am unsuccessfully trying to create a report using mysql/php, I would like to have rows as columns similar to Access Crosstab or Excel Pivot. I have sales staff & monthly sales which I would like to display across the page with month as column headers.

My query below outputs the data but every salesperson has a row for every month which doesnt read very well,

```
      Jan | Feb | Mar | April
```

Sales1
Sales2
Sales3
Sales4

```
Select
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName,
  Count(tblcases.CaseID) As cases,
  MonthName(tblcases.CaseDate) As Monthly
From
  tblcases Inner Join
  tblcontacts On tblcases.ContactAssignedTo =
  tblcontacts.ContactID
Group By
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName,
  MonthName(tblcases.CaseDate)  
  with rollup
```

Ant advice or pointers appreciated, I have researched but most of it went right over my head!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is simply group by each contact and use conditional aggregation to count rows based on each month:

```
SELECT
    a.ContactFullName,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 1) AS Jan,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 2) AS Feb,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 3) AS Mar,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 4) AS Apr,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 5) AS May,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 6) AS Jun,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 7) AS Jul,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 8) AS Aug,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 9) AS Sep,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 10) AS Oct,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 11) AS Nov,
    SUM(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 12) AS Dec
FROM
    tblcontacts a
INNER JOIN
    tblcases b ON a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo
GROUP BY
    a.ContactFullName
```

**Edit:** As per your comments to this answer: to get a price sum of each month, you can do something like:

```
SELECT
    a.ContactFullName,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 1, b.price, 0)) AS Jan,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 2, b.price, 0)) AS Feb,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 3, b.price, 0)) AS Mar,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 4, b.price, 0)) AS Apr,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 5, b.price, 0)) AS May,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 6, b.price, 0)) AS Jun,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 7, b.price, 0)) AS Jul,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 8, b.price, 0)) AS Aug,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 9, b.price, 0)) AS Sep,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 10, b.price, 0)) AS Oct,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 11, b.price, 0)) AS Nov,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(b.CaseDate) = 12, b.price, 0)) AS Dec
FROM
    tblcontacts a
INNER JOIN
    tblcases b ON a.ContactID = b.ContactAssignedTo
GROUP BY
    a.ContactFullName
```

Basically, for each row, if the casedate is in a particular month, pass the value of the `price` column to the `SUM` aggregation, otherwise, just pass it `0`.

Comment: Hi there, both fantastic answers and very helpful, thank you so much its exactly what I needed. I tried to see if this would also work using a column of currency value, what I would normally do is just add currency column and sum rather than the caseid. I have a column 'price' which contains summed values for the salesstaff per month but I cant see how you are caluclating in your code? Are you looking for how many times the ContactFullName appears against each month? If so I guess I wouldnt be able to sum price against each month in same way?

Comment: @gary, each `SUM` is only summing the result of boolean expressions (0 or 1), so it's basically just a count. If you want a sum of price for each month, see my latest edit.

Comment: many many thanks for your excellent explanation and code example, has set me on the road to learning a bit more about this, really has saved me a lot of time. regards

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
    tblcontacts.ContactFullName, 
    sum(case when MonthName(tblcases.CaseDate)='January' then 1 else 0 end) as January,
    sum(case when MonthName(tblcases.CaseDate)='February' then 1 else 0 end) as February,
    .
    .
    sum(case when MonthName(tblcases.CaseDate)='December' then 1 else 0 end) as December,
From 
  tblcases Inner Join 
  tblcontacts On tblcases.ContactAssignedTo = 
  tblcontacts.ContactID 
  Group By 
  tblcontacts.ContactFullName
```